# How to automatically trigger a selenium script after a code change

Tags: selenium, bitbucket

Does anyone know how selenium script can be automatically triggered whenever a code change is pushed to Bitbucket? Can this be achieved?

Comment: with something like Codeship for example? or are you talking about a "home-made" solution?

Comment: Use a CI tool such as Jenkins. You can get a plugin for bitbucket and jenkins integration. You can configure the job to trigger when code change is pushed to your repository. In the goals you can add how and what tests you want to run...

Comment: @Grasshopper, what plugin would you recommend for bitbucket and jenkins integration?

Comment: There is a BitBucket Plugin you can try - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BitBucket+Plugin

Comment: @Grasshopper, thank you . I shall explore the link.

Comment: This worked. Thanks